# SQL Server: get the first joined value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
ID  DEFINITION  VALUE
----------------------
1   A|B|C       1
2   A|All|All   3
3   A|B|All     6
4   All|B|All   4
```

The business logic behind that table is that the most specific DEFINITION of the 3 Values should be retrieved when passing a string. 'All' can be interpreted as '%'.

E.g. if i have a definition which is 'X|B|Z' -> the Value should be 4.
if i have 'A|B|C' -> the Value should be 1 (not 1,3,6,4) - only the most specific result should be retrieved starting from the right.

The '|' is just a separator.Each of the sub strings could be anything. I have chosen A-C in this example. Unfortunately its all concatenated in one column.

I am currently writing this query but it results with all matches unfortunately:`

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
              AND (T2.DEFINITION = CASE 
                                      WHEN T2.DEFINITION = 'A|B|C'
                                         THEN T2.DEFINITION
                                      WHEN T2.DEFINITION = 'A|ALL|C'
                                         THEN T2.DEFINITION
                                      WHEN T2.DEFINITION = 'ALL|B|C'
                                         THEN T2.DEFINITION
                                      WHEN T2.DEFINITION = 'ALL|ALL|C'
                                         THEN T2.DEFINITION
                                      WHEN T2.DEFINITION = 'A|B|ALL'
                                         THEN T2.DEFINITION....
                                      ELSE 'All|All|All'
                                   END)
```

I want to retrieve the first match of the case statement and not all of the matches. The order of that case statement is already reflects my business logic above.

Any ideas?

I fear the solution is very simple but I can't see it now.

Comment: It's very hard to decipher what you are asking for lol did you mean to join t2.definition to t2.definition in you AND clause?

Comment: `Unfortunately its all concatenated in one column` ... this is your real problem here.  You should normalize your data so that each piped value has its own row.

Comment: Your question mentions one table, but you sample code has two.  Very confusing.

Comment: Use a function to split the definition and "challenge" delimited strings into numbered elements, pair the elements by number, ignore the comparisons to "ALL" and sum the number of matches that remain. Is the largest number of matches always the winner or does _any_ mismatch disqualify the row? Tip: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Are the non-ALL choices always exactly one character, i.e. there is no possibility of getting tripped up by "ALL", "SHALLOW", "TALL", ...?

Comment: sorry it was late yesterday so i missed to mention, that i am joining T2 for the "Definition" column as this holds the string i want to check. T1 only has ID and Value. T2. ID and Definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you could do something like this:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where @str like replace(t.definition, 'All', '%')
order by (case when t.definition like '%All%All%All%' then 3
               when t.definition like '%All%All%' then 2
               when t.definition like '%All%' then 1
               else 0
          end) desc;
```

If you are trying to do this for values in a column, then you can use `apply` with a very similar approach.

Comment: could we also do dimensionality of the string dynamic ? e.g. if i would have more than 3 concatenated values?  e.g.   x|x|x|x or x|x|x|x|x ect.

Comment: @gnopfelbrie . . . Ask another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877164/sql-server-get-the-first-joined-result-based-on-business-logic

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
    ([ID] int, [DEFINITION] varchar(9), [VALUE] int)
;

INSERT INTO #TestTable
    ([ID], [DEFINITION], [VALUE])
VALUES
    (1, 'A|B|C', 1),
    (2, 'A|All|All', 3),
    (3, 'A|B|All', 6),
    (4, 'All|B|All', 4)
;

select [ID], [DEFINITION], [VALUE] from (
    SELECT T1.*, row_number() over (order by CASE 
                    WHEN T1.DEFINITION = 'A|B|C'
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN T1.DEFINITION = 'A|ALL|C'
                        THEN 2
                    WHEN T1.DEFINITION = 'ALL|B|C'
                        THEN 3
                    WHEN T1.DEFINITION = 'ALL|ALL|C'
                        THEN 4
                    WHEN T1.DEFINITION = 'A|B|ALL'
                        THEN 5
                    ELSE 6
                    END
                ) rnk
    FROM #TestTable T1
)T where rnk = 1
```

---

**Result :**

```
ID          DEFINITION VALUE
----------- ---------- -----------
1           A|B|C      1
```