# Get the first joined result based on business logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

My table T1 looks like this:

```
ID  VALUE
----------
1   1
2   32
3   6
4   42
5   8
6   62
7   43
8   34
```

My second T2 looks like this:

```
ID  DEFINITION
---------------
1   A|B|C     
2   er|All|All|B  
3   All|All|All   
4   All|bela|All 
5   All|All|All|G
6   A|All|All
7   All|B|All 
8   Av|All|All|G
```

The business logic behind that table is that the most specific DEFINITION should be applied and the respective value should be retrieved when passing a string. 'All' can be interpreted as '%'. The '|' is just a separator which defines how many values you are actually passing. Each of the strings could be anything...

E.g. if i have a definition which is 'X|B|Z' -> the Value should be 7. if i have'A|B|C' -> the Value should be 1 (not 1,6,7) - only the most specific result should be retrieved starting from the right which is the leave level.

I have already asked a pretty similar Question([SQL Server: get the first joined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848174/sql-server-get-the-first-joined-value)) and got this brilliant solution Gordon Linnof but unfortunately it does not cover more than 3 dimensions. I have now new Values in that table which could have more sub strings.

Is there any way to dynamically retrieve the right value?

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where @str like replace(t.definition, 'All', '%')
order by (case when t.definition like '%All%All%All%' then 3
               when t.definition like '%All%All%' then 2
               when t.definition like '%All%' then 1
               else 0
          end) asc;
```

Edit: I need to add more details to this question as Habo added some valid comments: the stringvalues represent alphanumeric id's e.g.T34 or ABC78 and can be varchar(255).

The less All values you have the more specific it is - which is the right one to choose.

Comment: Why is X|B|Z = 7 and A|B|C = 1?

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Mixing patterns with different numbers of `|` seems strange.  Can `'A|B|C'` match `'A|B|C|D'`

Comment: no the number of arguments defines which definition values you're looking at - means if if have three '|' than i have 4 values - only the strings with 3 '|' need to be taking into consideration

Comment: i think we're using sql server 2012. The reason why A|B|C is 1 is because there is an entry in the database for that. X|B|Z is not an entry in the db so you first look for X|B|All - if that is also not a valid value you look for X|All|Z , then X|All|All - then - All|B|All -which is a match hence 7.

Comment: And the [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848174/sql-server-get-the-first-joined-value) had this comment: "Use a function to split the definition and "challenge" delimited strings into numbered elements, pair the elements by number, ignore the comparisons to "ALL" and sum the number of matches that remain. Is the largest number of matches always the winner or does any mismatch disqualify the row? Tip: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question."

Comment: Have you contemplated this issue from the prior question? "Are the non-ALL choices always exactly one character, i.e. there is no possibility of getting tripped up by "ALL", "SHALLOW", "TALL", ...?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Declare @str VARCHAR(100) = 'A|B|C';

DECLARE
@Test TABLE
    (
         Id         INT
        ,Definition VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO
    @Test (Id, Definition)
VALUES
     (1, 'A|B|C')
    ,(2, 'er|All|All|B')
    ,(3, 'All|All|All')
    ,(4, 'All|bela|All')
    ,(5, 'All|All|All|G')
    ,(6, 'A|All|All')
    ,(7, 'All|B|All')
    ,(8, 'Av|All|All|G')
;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

WITH Tester AS
(
    SELECT
         Id
        ,Definition
        ,(LEN(Definition) - LEN(REPLACE(Definition, 'All', ''))) / LEN('All') AS numAlls
        ,REPLACE(Definition, 'All', '%') AS Mask
    FROM
        @Test
)

SELECT TOP 1
     Id
    ,Definition
FROM
    Tester
WHERE
    @str LIKE Mask
ORDER BY
     numAlls
```

The main key here being the column:

```
(LEN(Definition) - LEN(REPLACE(Definition, 'All', ''))) / LEN('All') AS numAlls
```

Basically, I'm taking the idea you gave with the ordering and simply making it more generic by simply counting the number of times the word `All` appears in the definition rather than explicitly creating multiple statements.

Hope that makes sense / does the trick!

---

**EDIT:**

For the sake of completeness and to address a truly valid point made by @HABO in the comments that the above solution would match any time the word `All` appeared in the string, even if it was part of another statement / word, the below solution is more robust / guarantees to only match cases where `All` is by itself:

```
WITH Tester AS
(
    SELECT
         Id
        ,Definition
        ,(LEN('|' + Definition + '|') - LEN(REPLACE('|' + Definition + '|', '|All|', ''))) / LEN('|All|') AS numAlls
        ,REPLACE('|' + Definition + '|', '|All|', '|%|') AS Mask
    FROM
        @Test
)

SELECT TOP 1
     Id
    ,Definition
FROM
    Tester
WHERE
    '|' + @str + '|' LIKE Mask
ORDER BY
     numAlls
```

Basically, you enclose the `Definition` with the separator character (`|`) to ensure every portion of the `Definition` begins and ends with the separator (which isn't the case for start / end values) then we can search for `|All|` throughout.

Hope that makes sense as to why this is a substantially more robust solution.

Comment: Note that this code does not correctly handle embedded "all". If `@str` is `'er|Shallower|BR549|B'` and the second `Definition` is `'er|Shallow|All|B'` you get curious results. The result is a match with the third definition (`'All|All|All'`) which doesn't even have the correct number of items. Testing `@str` as `'er|Shadow|BR549|B'` also shows a problem. The pattern for a wildcard match should be `'|All|'` instead of `'All'` and that requires adding `'|'` to each end of `Definition`.

Comment: Good comment, @HABO,I just didn't get that complicated since the example presented didn't seem to require it, but for the sake of completeness, I'll make an update now.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows a step-by-step approach to solving (my interpretation of) the problem. It does require a TVF to split the delimited strings into numbered items. The code for a suitable function is included at the end of the answer. Left as an exercise for the reader is figuring out which matches are *best*.

```
-- Sample "definitions".
--   'All' is a wildcard that matches any other string.
declare @Definitions as Table ( DefinitionId Int Identity, Definition VarChar(256) );
insert into @Definitions ( Definition ) values
  ( 'A|B|C' ), ( 'er|All|All|B' ), ( 'All|All|All' ), ( 'All|bela|All' ), ( 'All|All|All|G' ), ( 'A|All|All' ), ( 'All|B|All' ), ( 'Av|All|All|G' );
select * from @Definitions;

-- Sample candidate string to match against "definitions".
--   NB: 'All' has no special meaning here.
declare @Candidates as Table ( CandidateId Int Identity, Candidate VarChar(256) );
insert into @Candidates ( Candidate ) values
  ( 'A|B|C' ), ( 'X|B|Z' ), ( 'Allow|This|All|G' );
select * from @Candidates;

-- Demonstrate splitting the definitions.
select D.DefinitionId, D.Definition, SD.ItemNumber, SD.Item,
  case when SD.Item = 'All' then 1 else 0 end as MatchAny
  from @Definitions as D cross apply
    ( select ItemNumber, Item from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K( D.Definition, '|' ) ) as SD;

-- Demonstrate splitting the candidates.
select C.CandidateId, C.Candidate, SC.ItemNumber, SC.Item
  from @Candidates as C cross apply
    ( select ItemNumber, Item from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K( C.Candidate, '|' ) ) as SC;

-- Break the task into reasonable simple steps.
with
  -- Split the definitions into individual items.
  SplitDefinitions as (
    select D.DefinitionId, D.Definition, SD.ItemNumber, SD.Item,
      case when SD.Item = 'All' then 1 else 0 end as MatchAny
      from @Definitions as D cross apply
        ( select ItemNumber, Item from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K( D.Definition, '|' ) ) as SD ),
  -- Split the candidates into individual items.
  SplitCandidates as (
    select C.CandidateId, C.Candidate, SC.ItemNumber, SC.Item
      from @Candidates as C cross apply
        ( select ItemNumber, Item from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K( C.Candidate, '|' ) ) as SC ),
  -- Get the count items in each definition.
  DefinitionItemCounts as (
    select DefinitionId, Max( ItemNumber ) as ItemCount
      from SplitDefinitions
      group by DefinitionId ),
  -- Get the count items in each candidate.
  CandidateItemCounts as (
    select CandidateId, Max( ItemNumber ) as ItemCount
      from SplitCandidates
      group by CandidateId ),
  -- Get the pairs of candidates and definitions that have the same number of items.
  CandidateDefinitionPairs as (
    select CIC.CandidateId, DIC.DefinitionId
      from CandidateItemCounts as CIC inner join
        DefinitionItemCounts as DIC on DIC.ItemCount = CIC.ItemCount )
  -- For pairs of candidate and definition with the same number of items calculate the number of matches.
  -- Tip: The following statement may be replaced to see the intermediate results, e.g.:
  --   select * from CandidateDefinitionPairs 
  select CDP.CandidateId, Max( SC.Candidate ) as Candidate, CDP.DefinitionId, Max( SD.Definition ) as Definition,
    Sum( case when SC.Item = SD.Item then 1 else SD.MatchAny end ) as Matches
    from CandidateDefinitionPairs as CDP inner join
      SplitCandidates as SC on SC.CandidateId = CDP.CandidateId inner join
      SplitDefinitions as SD on SD.DefinitionId = CDP.DefinitionId and SD.ItemNumber = SC.ItemNumber
    group by CDP.CandidateId, CDP.DefinitionId
    order by CDP.CandidateId, Matches desc, CDP.DefinitionId;
```

The splitter, chosen rather randomly from those at hand, is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l;
```